# How do I get the max record?

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Following is my sql code:

```
SELECT
    v.veh_manufname AS "Manufacturer Name",
    COUNT(o.off_no) AS "Total No. of Offences"
FROM
    VEHICLE v JOIN OFFENCE o ON v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin
GROUP BY 
    v.veh_manufname
```

Running the above sql code returns:

```
 Manufacturer Name    Total Offences
    Audi                      3
    Honda                     1
    Mack                      3
    Kia                       1
    Mercedes Benz             1
    Ferrari                   4
    Yamaha                    1
    BMW                       2
    Mini                      1
    Toyota                    1
    Harley Davidson           1
    Mazda                     4
```

How and where do I put the Max aggregate function which will give me the record with the maximum offences only.

Required Output is:

```
Manufacturer Name    Total Offences
      Ferrari             4
      Mazda               4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward method uses `RANK`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        v.veh_manufname AS "Manufacturer Name",
        COUNT(o.off_no) AS "Total No. of Offences",
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(o.off_no) DESC) rnk
    FROM VEHICLE v
    INNER JOIN OFFENCE o ON v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin
    GROUP BY v.veh_manufname
)

SELECT "Manufacturer Name", "Total No. of Offences"
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

We could also use a subquery to restrict to only those vehicles with the max number of offences:

```
SELECT "Manufacturer Name", "Total No. of Offences"
FROM cte
WHERE "Total No. of Offences" = (SELECT MAX("Total No. of Offences") FROM cte);
```

If you wanted a direct modification of your current query, without using a CTE, you could tag on a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    v.veh_manufname AS "Manufacturer Name",
    COUNT(o.off_no) AS "Total No. of Offences"
FROM VEHICLE v
INNER JOIN OFFENCE o ON v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin
GROUP BY v.veh_manufname
HAVING COUNT(o.off_no) = (SELECT MAX(max_off)
                          FROM (SELECT COUNT(o.off_no) AS max_off
                                FROM VEHICLE v
                                INNER JOIN OFFENCE o ON v.veh_vin = o.veh_vin
                                GROUP BY v.veh_manufname) t);
```

Comment: Without using RANK, but instead using MAX; do you think there is a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is, you can use a subquery, see my updated answer.  Rank is probably faster though.

Comment: Okay one more thing I wanted to ask? Is there a way to do this without using the WITH function and only subqueries?

Comment: Yes, simply replace `cte` in my two queries with the entire content of the CTE definition.  What do you get?  Some very bloated Oracle code, especially for the second query.  This is one reason to use CTEs, because it avoids code duplication.

Comment: Do you think the sql code given in my question (at the top) can be altered to straightaway get the desired output (without using WITH function or RANDOM function). Do I have to show my tables for this?

Comment: I have also added this option to my answer.

Comment: Think that will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without subqueries but there's problem:
*What if you have two or more manufacturers with equally the highest number of offences?*
The `RANK()` function is useful, or you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery:

```
                x.offences
From            (SELECT         v.veh_manufname,
                                COUNT(o.off_no) OVER (PARTITION BY v.veh_manufname) AS offences,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.veh_manufname ORDER BY o.off_no DESC) AS n
                From            VEHICLE v (NOLOCK)
                Left Outer Join OFFENCE o (NOLOCK) On o.veh_vin = v.veh_vin
                ) AS x
Order By        x.offences DESC,
                x.n DESC
```

This will give a single result, where the manufacturer with the most offences and the most recent offence will be displayed.